# ByteBuddy - get annotation of declaring class inside intercept()

Tags: java, reflection, byte-buddy

I need to get the annotation (a value inside of it) of the declaring class of a method during `intercept()`:

```
@RuntimeType
    public static Object intercept(@SuperCall Callable callable, @Origin Method method) throws Exception {
        method.getDeclaringClass().getDeclaredAnnotation(SomeAnnotationOnClass.class);
```

The last line returns null.

```
new AgentBuilder.Default().with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemOut()).type(ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith(SomeAnnotationOnClass.class))
                .transform((builder, type, clazzLoader, javaModule) -> {
                    return builder.method(ElementMatchers.any()).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(MyInterceptor.class));
```

This works though... So the annotation is present (on class level!). But not when `intercept()` is called

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own binder that is executed during instrumentation where the class file-level information is still available. Assuming you define an annotation `@interface Foo` with runtime retention, you can implement some:

```
class FooBinder extends ParameterBinder.ForFixedValue<Foo>
```

where you can extract the constant value from the annotation. This value is then made available to any interceptor method annotated with `@Foo`.

Comment: Thanks!
Is there any documentation concerning how to bind the transformation to the ParameterBinder.ForFixedValue when using the AgentBuilder? 
I couldn't find any.

Comment: There is much less documentation then what I would like but the javadoc can help you out! You are using `MethodDelegation.withCustomBinding().bind(...).to(...)` for this.